# REST API User Image Comment resource

Tags: api, rest, url

Let's say I have these three resources: User, Image and Comment

The comments belong to the image, not the user, but the user can make comments on an image.

Now let's say I want to get all the images that the user has commented on.

What would be the RESTful way of doing this?

```
GET /users/:id/commented_images
```

or

```
GET /images?commented_user_id=:id
```

or

Something else?

I'm not sure if I should go through the User resource or the Image resource.

Answer (score 0):

REST URLS should represent some entity and can be fetched using its attribute. As comment is an attribute of Image entity so using the following make more sense:

```
GET /images?commented_user_id=:id
```